# Changing a character of a string in a 2D string array causes Segmentation fault

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, declaration, c-strings, string-literals

I have a 2D array of char* created like this :

```
char *rows[][4] = {
    {"A1","A2","A3"},
    {"B1","B2","B3"}
};
```

Then i want to change an char in this array. With my limited experience i would do it like this :

```
rows[0][0][0] = 'G';
```

And I'd expect the "A1" to change to "G1". Instead i get a Seg fault.
How do I do this ?

Comment: You have an array of *pointers* to string literals, which are read-only. You are trying to write `'G'` into one of those strings. You could change the array element to point to a *different* string, say `rows[0][0] = "G1";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This declaration

```
char *rows[][4] = {
    {"A1","A2","A3"},
    {"B1","B2","B3"}
};
```

declares a multi-dimensional array of pointers to string literals.

You may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined**

Declare the array of strings the following way

```
char rows[][4][3] = {
    {"A1","A2","A3"},
    {"B1","B2","B3"}
};
```

Pay attention to that as the second dimension of the array is equal to `4` while you specified only three initializers for sub-arrays then the declaration looks like

```
char rows[][4][3] = {
    {"A1","A2","A3", ""},
    {"B1","B2","B3", ""}
};
```

Now you may write

```
rows[0][0][0] = 'G';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the strings will be length 2, you can use this:

```
  char rows[2][3][3] = {
    {"A1","A2","A3"},
    {"B1","B2","B3"}
  };
  printf("%c\n", rows[0][0][0]); //Prints "A"
  printf("%s\n", rows[0][0]); //Prints "A1"

  rows[0][0][0] = 'G';

  printf("%c\n", rows[0][0][0]); //Prints "G"
  printf("%s\n", rows[0][0]); //Prints "G1"
```

Note that you need rows[2][3][3] instead of rows[2][3][2] when the string are of length 2 because in c every string ends with the '\0' character.

If you want to support strings of different sizes, you also could create your strings using [malloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm). Let me know if you want more details about this.